# Is there a way to shutdown the X display?

Tags: display, command-line

I know about `startx`, but is there a command that stops X? I run Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X is currently handled by `gdm` (Gnome Display Manager). The "proper" way for starting, stopping and restarting the graphical server is:

```
sudo stop gdm
sudo start gdm
sudo restart gdm
```

Commands like `startx` aren't recommended as they're not setting important environment variables or neccessarily pulling in the right configuration. Using `startx` instead of `gdm` also makes it harder to close ;)

Comment: If gdm is used. Otherwise substitute gdm with kdm (in case of Kubuntu)

Comment: I use kdm. Thanks for the help, now I don't need to use a GUI all the time!